# Where to Put the Login ViewController in Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, appdelegate

What would be the best approach in Xcode, if I want to have a MainViewController, which is only shown if the user is logged in, otherwise a LoginViewController is shown and after the (successfull) login the MainViewController.

**Focusing first on Storyboard:**

- (a) Have a LoginViewController (as initial View Controller) and then
  a segue to the MainViewController
- (b) Have the MainViewController (as
  initial View Controller) and a connection to the LoginViewController,
  which will be used if the user is not logged in
- (c) Like (a) but in a
  NavigationController embedded

Or are there other possibilities?

**Focusing on the code-logic:** 
Should this be handled in the AppDelegate or in the Login- respective MainViewController

If somebody has example code, would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(c)

I typically make the LoginVC as the initial VC.

- Logically, the user already being logged in is a special sub-case of
  the "Login Use Case". So it makes sense to use that as a starting
  point.
- Having the LoginVC as the base of your nav hierarchy also makes it
  easy to log out using `popToViewController:animated`, regardless of
  where they were in the nav stack.

Handle transitioning to the MainVC from within the LoginVC, not the app delegate. This way you'll have one set of code to do the transition, the only difference being in one case the user supplies the credentials and in the other case the credentials are cached.

Once the credentials are confirmed use your segue to move to the MainVC:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainVCViewSegue" sender:nil];
```

Comment: Does `popToViewController:animated` work outside a navigationcontroller? In the documentation I find it within __UINavigationController Class Reference__.

Comment: Only works within a nav controller. Is there a reason you wouldn't be using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: No. Just wanted to be sure that I understood it correct. As this would be my solution c) not a).